# CoreData Fetch request returning fault - how to access the actual object/value from core data?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I am working on an app in swiftUI. I selected 'use core data' when creating the project and so the boiler plate code for coredata was included in the project.

In the entities/attributes configuration I have created an entity called Users with a string attribute called username.

I used the provided core data functions to save a username 'John'. when I try to fetch the value however, I get the below instead of the actual user name.

> FetchedResults(results: <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6000010d85b0>(
> <Users: 0x6000031f9e00> (entity: Users; id: 0x972ee5e326034de5 x-coredata://ABB653C3-72E7-457F-9ACD-4A99FC82DC92/Users/p1; data: <fault>)
> )

I understand a 'fault' is not an error, but i obviously need to get access to the actual value i saved and not the above result.

Here is the code for my view. When I try to list the content of users, I get the mentioned response and not the actual username.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Download: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Users.username, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)

    private var users: FetchedResults<Users>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
         
            List(users) { user in
                
                Text("\(user)")
                
                
            }
            
            
            Button("Click Here") {
                
               
                print(users.count)
                print(users)
                
                    
                }
            
        }
        
        
            
        }
    }


struct Download_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Download()
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the function i used to save the username value:

```
private func addUser(name: String) {
        withAnimation {
            let newUser = Users(context: viewContext)
            newUser.username = name

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Printing the count of the array size to the console gives me the correct value (i.e., 1). So my save seems to have worked.

Just can't get the actual value of 'John' to be outputted to my view or the console.

Comment: Where's the fault you are referring to? The output looks just fine for what you are printing. If you want the username then change `Text("\(user)")` to `Text(user.username)`. I'm assuming your `Users` entity has a `username` field of type `String`.

Comment: haha oh boy I swear I tried that. I must've been at this too long tonight. Yes, of course that worked. Thanks so much for opening my eyes.

Comment: It can also be helpful to have your `Users` entity confirm to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement the `description` property to return a useful string representation. And you should rename your Users entity to User since each record represents a single user.

Answer (score -1):

1. Pass the NSFetchRequest to propertyWrapper directly with marking [`returnsObjectsAsFaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506756-returnsobjectsasfaults) as false.
2. Just access the alive `NSManagedObject`'s instance property ( aka [`Firing Faults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH18-SW1))

> Firing Faults
> Fault handling is transparent—you do not have to execute a fetch to realize a fault. If at some stage a persistent property of a fault object is accessed, Core Data automatically retrieves the data for the object and initializes the object. This process is commonly referred to as firing the fault. If you access a property on the Department object — its name, for example — the fault fires and Core Data executes a fetch for you to retrieve all of the object's attributes. (See NSManagedObject for a list of methods that do not cause faults to fire.)